# What is the differences between MODE_IN_CALL, MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, MODE_CALL_SCREENING?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-audio-streams

This is what the file says, but I can't fully understand.

```
/* modes for setMode/getMode/setRoute/getRoute */
    /**
     * Audio harware modes.
     */
    /**
     * Invalid audio mode.
     */
    public static final int MODE_INVALID            = AudioSystem.MODE_INVALID;
    /**
     * Current audio mode. Used to apply audio routing to current mode.
     */
    public static final int MODE_CURRENT            = AudioSystem.MODE_CURRENT;
    /**
     * Normal audio mode: not ringing and no call established.
     */
    public static final int MODE_NORMAL             = AudioSystem.MODE_NORMAL;
    /**
     * Ringing audio mode. An incoming is being signaled.
     */
    public static final int MODE_RINGTONE           = AudioSystem.MODE_RINGTONE;
    /**
     * In call audio mode. A telephony call is established.
     */
    public static final int MODE_IN_CALL            = AudioSystem.MODE_IN_CALL;
    /**
     * In communication audio mode. An audio/video chat or VoIP call is established.
     */
    public static final int MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION   = AudioSystem.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION;
    /**
     * Call screening in progress. Call is connected and audio is accessible to call
     * screening applications but other audio use cases are still possible.
     */
    public static final int MODE_CALL_SCREENING     = AudioSystem.MODE_CALL_SCREENING;
```

Could you please explain them with examples?

At the moment, I use video chat service on WebView and I get `MODE_CALL_SCREENING`, it uses media volume, It should use 'calling' volume. How can I force it?

Answer (score 1):

MODE_IN_CALL
You are talking to someone over audio only call (normal telephone call)

MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
you are video & audio chatting with your friend or calling them on VoIP

MODE_CALL_SCREENING
your phone is ringing and you are checking then number before you answer the phone

Comment: Could you please some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The mode parameter is defined in the AudioSystem class to set the state of the phone

**MODE_IN_CALL**: Incoming call mode. A phone call is established.

`Constant Value:` `2 (0x00000002)`

```
public static final int MODE_IN_CALL 





private void setAudioNormal() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
  }
}
```

Another example

```
import android.media.AudioManager; 
public void startOutgoingRinger(OutgoingRinger.Type type) {
    AudioManager audioManager = ServiceUtil.getAudioManager(context);
    audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);

    if (type == OutgoingRinger.Type.SONAR) {
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    } else {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    }

    outgoingRinger.start(type);
}
```

**MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION**: In communication audio mode. An audio/video chat or VoIP communications are established.

`Constant Value:` `3 (0x00000003)`

```
public static final int MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION



  private void chooseVoiceMode() {
      AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      if(mAudioConfiguration.aec) {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
      } else {
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
      }
    }
```

**MODE_CALL_SCREENING**: Call screening in progress. There is a call connected but the audio is not in use.
Call screening: It is the process of identifying an incoming caller, giving information about the caller, and determining how best to respond to that call.

`Constant Value:` `4 (0x00000004)`

```
public static final int MODE_CALL_SCREENING





public int getMode() {
    final IAudioService service = getService();
    try {
        int mode = service.getMode();
        int sdk;
        try {
            sdk = getContext().getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // some tests don't have a Context
            sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        }
        if (mode == MODE_CALL_SCREENING && sdk <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            mode = MODE_IN_CALL;
        }
        return mode;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw e.rethrowFromSystemServer();
    }
}
```

[Click here For more examples](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.media.AudioManager/)

Comment: could you add an explanation when to use which and why? What are the benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: If you read the answers, you will find that I explain them in the answers.

Comment: I read your answer, and it is useful, but you did not explain why to use one over the other. What is the effect/benefit of these flags? For e.g. I replace MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION with MODE_IN_CALL in my application, what will change? How will the user be effected?

Comment: `MODE_IN_CALL`:  A phone call 
`MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`: An audio/video chat or VoIP communications
`MODE_CALL_SCREENING`: identifying an incoming caller, giving information about the caller, and determining how best to respond to that call